# Remove repeated values in different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
>>>Feature name   error1    error2    error3   error4
0     1     A      overlaps  overlaps  overlaps overlaps
1     2     B       No error 
2     3     C       overlaps  invalid   invalid  
3     4     D     invalid   overlaps  overlaps
```

I would like to have for each row unique errors only, e.g:

```
>>>Feature Name   error1    error2    error3   error4
0     1      A    overlaps  
1     2      B    No error 
2     3      C    overlaps  invalid     
3     4      D    invalid   overlaps
```

Is there any simple way to get this? I thought maybe to count the number of times each value appears per row but then i'm not sure how to remove them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is remove duplicates from `error` columns, add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add possible removed columns and assign back:

```
cols = df.filter(like='error').columns
df[cols] = (df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.unique()), axis=1)
                    .reindex(np.arange(len(cols)), axis=1))
print (df)
   Feature name    error1    error2  error3  error4
0        1    A  overlaps       NaN     NaN     NaN
1        2    B        No     error     NaN     NaN
2        3    C  overlaps   invalid     NaN     NaN
3        4    D   invalid  overlaps     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: those two created the same table as I had at the beginning

Comment: I have edited my question - it has more columns beside error and feature

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
out = pd.DataFrame(list(map(pd.unique, df.loc[:,'error1':].values)),index=df.Feature)
Out[333]: 
                0         1     2
Feature                          
1        overlaps      None  None
2              No     error  None
3        overlaps   invalid  None
4         invalid  overlaps  None
```